# InfoPath unable to submit to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-form

We run SharePoint 2010.  All users connect to network via Citrix running on top op Windows 2008.  We have Info Path (2013) forms that we publish to SharePoint.  All works great.

We are exploring migrating users to Windows 2016 with RDS and doing away with Citrix.  We have setup a test Windows 2016 server and several people in IT are testing it.  One thing we have found is that we are unable to submit InfoPath forms on Windows 2016 to our existing SharePoint 2010 deployment.  We also see a smilar issue if trying to update the design of an and existing InfoPath form and try to publish to the same library.  An error comes up stating:
"InfoPath cannot submit the form.
An error occurred while the form was being submitted.
The form cannot be submitted to the following location: http://sharepointfe/Departments/MIS/Notable Events/The site may be offline, read-only, or otherwise unavailable.
The parameter is incorrect."[image]

If we hop back on a Windows 2008 Citrix session, the form submits fine.  We can also update formatting on the form and publish. These users have full ownership of the library that they are trying to submit the form to.  As a test, we also stood up a SharePoint 2016 server and a test site and we are seeing the same issues there.

I am at a loss.  Any thoughts?

Comment: any firewall restrictions for particular OS enforced? Can you browse site in IE on the machine where you face issue?